# Should say “his own wife” or “his wife”?

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality, expressions

I was narrating a movie to my friend where I made a statement like “*his own wife killed him*” where my friend said it doesn’t sound right to say “*his **own** wife*” and corrected me to say it as just “*his wife*”. Can someone please let me know what’s the correct usage?

Comment: I don't see any problem with your usage of "own". It would possibly emphasize the unlikely idea that someone close to the victim killed him. It would depend on your intent.

Comment: "His own wife" is perfectly acceptable (a) to avoid ambiguity, if more than one wife has been mentioned, or (b) as you used it, to stress the significance of the relationship.